# Vue 3 Unit Test cannot get to element

Tags: vue.js, jestjs

I have a Vue 3 project that uses PrimeVue.  In my template I have a PrimeVue dialog component:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <Button data-testid="showButton" label="Show" @click="openDialog" />
    <Dialog v-if="showDialog" data-testid="myDialog">
      <template #header>
        <h3 data-testid="dialogHeader">My Header</h3>
      </template>
    </Dialog>
  </div>
</template>
```

I can test that the dialog is initially hidden and then subsequently displayed by using .exists() e.g

```
it('should not display a dialog initially', () => {
        expect(wrapper.findComponent(Dialog).exists()).toBe(false)
})

it('should display a dialog when button is clicked', async() => {
        const showButton = wrapper.find('[data-testid="showButton"]');
        showButton.trigger('click');
        await nextTick();
        expect(wrapper.findComponent(Dialog).exists()).toBe(true)
})
```

but I am unable to take the test any further.  I would like to test that "My Header" is displayed in the dialog for instance but I am unable to get a handle on that header.  Nothing I have tried works for example the following test:

```
it('should display the correct heading', async() => {
        const showButton = wrapper.find('[data-testid="showButton"]');
        showButton.trigger('click');
        await nextTick();
        const dialogHeader = wrapper.find('[data-testid="dialogHeader"]');
        console.log(dialogHeader);
})
```

returns

```
[Object: null prototype] {}
```

in the console.  Can anyone help me?

Answer (score -2):

you can use

```
const showButton = wrapper.find("button[data-testid='showButton']");
```

Comment: It's not the button I am trying to get to - I have no problem with the button - that test works fine.  It's the header element of the Dialog I am trying to get to.

Comment: ok you can try `wrapper.element.getAttribute('data-testid')`

Comment: That doesn't work either - everything I try to get to with that PrimeVue Dialog seems to be null

Comment: @RichardShergold please can you share the html of the header you want to test?

Comment: I did - in the original post.

Comment: `wrapper.find("Dialog[data-testid='showButton']")`

Comment: Or is the `dialog` a custom component?

Comment: Dialog is a component from the PrimeVue component library

Comment: Maybe that's why it's not working